# Como resolver um Notice: Undefined index?

Tags: php, html

<kbd>[image: SS]</kbd>

Iniciando em PHP e seguindo um tutorial usei o código acima e acabei recebendo este erro:

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\wamp\www\mezzo-com\reservas.php on line 3

Como resolvê-lo?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 25):

Como está o formulário que chama o `C:\wamp\www\mezzo-com\reservas.php`?

Ele precisa ter um botão sendo postado que mande informações para o *script* PHP. Deve ter algo como:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
```

Na verdade é possível que você tenha problemas com outros campos (`name`, `mail`, `age`, `people`, etc.) Sem conhecer a página que chama o *script* fica complicado dar informações mais precisas. Mas é possível que você sequer esteja submetendo um formulário e chamando o *script* PHP direto. Ou está chamando mas enviando com `GET` ao invés de `POST`. Deve existir algo como:

```
<form action="reservas.php" method="post">
```

Mas se você estiver chamando o *script* em um contexto em que estes dados não estão disponíveis, aí você precisa fazer com que o acesso ao elemento não aconteça trocando seu `if` na linha 3 para:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/Form.html).

Assim você verifica a existência da variável e seu índice sem tentar acessar seu valor, até porque o valor dele não é importante e sim sua existência. Você estará verificando se a operação pode ser feita antes de deixar a falha ocorrer.

Answer (score 15):

Esse erro indica que não há um valor na sua variável `$_POST` com o nome `"submit"`. Ou seu formulário não incluiu esse campo, ou a requisição não é um `POST` (não estou certo quanto a essa segunda possibilidade, pois não tenho experiência prática com PHP).

Verifique o formulário que chama essa URL. Mas se quiser tornar seu código mais robusto, você pode verificar se a chave existe antes de usá-la, através da função [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php) ou [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) (o segundo também checa se o valor é nulo):

```
if (array_key_exists("submit", $_POST)){    // Entra se "submit" existe

if (isset($_POST["submit"])){               // Entra se "submit" existe e não é null
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é a falta do campo submit no seu form.

Certifique-se de que o método do form está como POST, caso contrário, o html por padrão usará GET.