# Exibir as informações do usuário em outra página

Tags: php, sql

Tenho uma página para login (login.php) e uma que gostaria que exibisse todos os dados do usuário (profile.php), dei uma pesquisada e vi que usando Sessions isso seria possível, fiz o código, baseado nos exemplos que vi, mas fica retornando um erro ao acessar a profile.php.

> Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined index: sobrenome in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 29
>
> Notice: Undefined index: emaill in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 30
>
> Notice: Undefined index: senha in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 31
>
> Notice: Undefined index: telefone in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cpf in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 33
>
> Notice: Undefined index: rua in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 34
>
> Notice: Undefined index: numero in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 35
>
> Notice: Undefined index: bairro in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 36
>
> Notice: Undefined index: cidade in C:\xampp\htdocs\Soldwear\user\profile.php on line 37

Vou deixar os códigos aqui, espero que possam me ajudar.

```
Login.php

<?php require_once('../Connections/db_site.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
?>
<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['email'];
  $password=$_POST['senha'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "profile.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "login.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_db_site, $db_site);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE emailClientes=$loginUsername";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($sql = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $nome = $sql["nomeClientes"]; 
    $sobrenome = $sql["sobrenomeClientes"];
    $emaill = $sql["emailClientes"];
    $senha = $sql["senhaClientes"];
    $telefone = $sql["telefoneClientes"];
    $cpf = $sql["cpfClientes"];
    $rua = $sql["ruaClientes"];
    $numero = $sql["numeroClientes"];
    $bairro = $sql["bairroClientes"];
    $cidade = $sql["cidadeClientes"];
    $_SESSION['nome']=$nome;
    $_SESSION['sobrenome']=$sobrenome;
    $_SESSION['emaill']=$emaill;
    $_SESSION['senha']=$senha;
    $_SESSION['telefone']=$telefone;
    $_SESSION['cpf']=$cpf;
    $_SESSION['rua']=$rua;
    $_SESSION['numero']=$numero;
    $_SESSION['bairro']=$bairro;
    $_SESSION['cidade']=$cidade;
    }

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT emailClientes, senhaClientes FROM clientes WHERE emailClientes=%s AND senhaClientes=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $db_site) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
     $loginStrGroup = "";

    if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
    //declare two session variables and assign them
    $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
    $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;
       if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
      $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
    }
    header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
    header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Entrar - Soldwear</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Zilla+Slab:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" href="../img/logo.png">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="cabecalho">
        <a href="../index.php">
            <h1 class="logo">SOLDWEAR</h1>
        </a>
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="btn-menu"><a href="../index.php"><p class="fa fa-home"></p></a></div>
        <div class="btn-menu"><a href="../loja/produtos.php"><p class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></p></a></div>
        <div class="btn-menu"><a href="../rastrear.php"><p class="fa fa-map-marker"></p></a></div>
        <div class="btn-menu"><a href="profile.php"><p class="fa fa-user"></p></a></div>
    </div>
    </header>
    <div class="corpoSite">
    <p>LOGIN</p>
      <form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" name="form1" method="POST">
        <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="100%" class="center"><label>Email:
              <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
            </label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="100%" class="center"><label>Senha:
              <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha">
            </label></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <p>
          <input name="enviar" type="submit" class="botao" value="Entrar">
        </p>
      </form>

    </div>
    <div class="rodape">
      <div class="rodapeA">
        <p>Soldwear</p>
        <p>Rua São Paulo, 973 - Blumenau (SC)</p>
        <p>sold.wear73@gmail.com | (47) 99970-7076</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rodapeA">
        <p class="fa fa-facebook"></p>
        <p class="fa fa-twitter"></p>
        <p class="fa fa-instagram"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


profile.php
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <head>
        <title>Entrar - Soldwear</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700|Zilla+Slab:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="icon" href="../img/logo.png">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="cabecalho">
            <a href="../index.php">
                <h1 class="logo">SOLDWEAR</h1>
            </a>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="btn-menu"><a href="../index.php"><p class="fa fa-home"></p></a></div>
            <div class="btn-menu"><a href="../loja/produtos.php"><p class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></p></a></div>
            <div class="btn-menu"><a href="../rastrear.php"><p class="fa fa-map-marker"></p></a></div>
            <div class="btn-menu"><a href="profile.php"><p class="fa fa-user"></p></a></div>
        </div>
        </header>
        <div class="corpoSite">
          <?php
        echo $_SESSION['nome'];
        echo $_SESSION['sobrenome'];
        echo $_SESSION['emaill'];
        echo $_SESSION['senha'];
        echo $_SESSION['telefone'];
        echo $_SESSION['cpf'];
        echo $_SESSION['rua'];
        echo $_SESSION['numero'];
        echo $_SESSION['bairro'];
        echo $_SESSION['cidade']; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="rodape">
          <div class="rodapeA">
            <p>Soldwear</p>
            <p>Rua São Paulo, 973 - Blumenau (SC)</p>
            <p>sold.wear73@gmail.com | (47) 99970-7076</p>
          </div>
          <div class="rodapeA">
            <p class="fa fa-facebook"></p>
            <p class="fa fa-twitter"></p>
            <p class="fa fa-instagram"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?> tem que ser primeira linha do php Qualquer output que tiver antes do session_start(), inclusive um espaço em branco, vai dar problema com a sessão. Os erros Undefined index pode ver aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21714/como-resolver-um-notice-undefined-index

Answer (score 0):

No código profile.php retira o `<?php session_start(); ?>`, Se você inicia duas sessões ao mesmo tempo, o php não consegue executar.

Comment: são duas paginas diferentes, uma é login.php e outra profile.php.