# erro ao cadastrar no banco

Tags: php, html

Está aparecendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Notice: Undefined index: razao_social in C:\xampp2\htdocs\estudo\cadastroPrestador.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: nome_fantasia in C:\xampp2\htdocs\estudo\cadastroPrestador.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\estudo\cadastroPrestador.php on line 12
erro ao tentar cadastrar
```

conecta.php:

```
<?php
    $servidor='localhost';
    $usuario='root';
    $senha='';
    $bancodedados='cis';


    $strcon = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$bancodedados);
?>
```

cadastroPrestador.php:

```
    <?php
    include_once("conecta.php");



    $idPrest = $_POST['id'];
    $razaoSoc = $_POST['razao_social'];
    $NomeFanta = $_POST['nome_fantasia'];
    $NumCnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
    $Tip = ['tipo'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO cadastroprestador(ID_PREST,Razão_Social,Nome_Fantasia,CNPJ) VALUES ('$idPrest', '$razaoSoc', '$NomeFanta', '$NumCnpj')";
    mysqli_query($sql) or die ("erro ao tentar cadastrar");
    mysql_close($strcon);
    echo "Cadastrado Com sucesso";
?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Cadastro Prestador</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- menu -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cadastro de Prestador</a>
        </div>

  </div>
 </nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Prestador</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form name "Ficha1" action="cadastroprestador.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group" id="Prestador">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="ex1">ID</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="id" type="text" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label for="ex2">Razão Social</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="razao_social" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex3">Nome Fantasia</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="nome_fantasia" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex4">CNPJ</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="CNPJ" type="text">
            </div>      
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex6">Tipo</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
                            <option>HOSPITAL</option>
                            <option>CLINICA</option>
                            <option>LABORATORIO</option>
                            <option>REMOÇÃO</option>
                            </select>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex5">Indicação</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="indicacao">
                        <option>Prospecção</option>
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                        </select>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-2 right" id="btn_cad">Cadastro</button>      

        </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solução: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21714/como-resolver-um-notice-undefined-index

Comment: No caso do seu código, o interessante seria inserir o isset assim como explica no tópico que coloquei o link.

A atribuição do campo "tipo" tá sem o $.post no arquivo PHP.

Comment: Sempre que uma resposta resolver seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Aproveita e faça um tour https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Erros no seu script**

Não é `mysqli_query($sql)` e sim  `mysqli_query($strcon,$sql)`

Não é `mysql_close($strcon);` e sim `mysqli_close($strcon);`

As variáveis $_POST como você bem deve saber recebe os dados passados por uma requisição HTTP POST. Provavelmente essas variáveis não foram passadas ainda na requisição e por isso não existem. Não adianta chamar algo que não existe.

### Solução

Faça validação do lado cliente e do lado servidor. Dessa forma vai evitar o erro `Notice: Undefined index` e **evitar um INSERT sem valores**.

- **Do lado cliente**: O atributo required.

  Esse é um atributo booleano usado para indicar que um determinando campo de formulário é obrigatório para o envio do mesmo. Ao adicionar esse atributo a um campo de formulário, o navegador obriga o usuário a inserir dados naquele campo antes de enviar o formulário.

  Essa validação substitui a validação básica de formulário implementada com JavaScript, tornando as coisas um pouco mais úteis e nos poupando algum tempo de desenvolvimento

  Exemplos:

  `<input class="form-control required" name="id" type="text" required>`

  `<select class="form-control" name="tipo" required>`
- **Do lado servidor**

  ```
  // Cria uma variável que terá os dados do erro
  $erro = false;

  // Verifica se o POST tem algum valor
  if ( !isset( $_POST ) || empty( $_POST ) ) {
      $erro = 'Nada foi postado.';
  }

  // Cria as variáveis dinamicamente
  foreach ( $_POST as $chave => $valor ) {
      // Remove todas as tags HTML
      // Remove os espaços em branco do valor
      $valor=trim($valor);
      $$chave = trim( strip_tags( $valor ) );

      // Verifica se tem algum valor nulo
      if ( empty ( $valor ) || $valor=="" ) {
          $erro = 'Existem campos em branco.';
      }
  }

  // Se existir algum erro, mostra o erro
  if ( $erro ) {
      echo $erro;
  } else {
      // Se a variável erro continuar com valor falso
      // Faça o INSERT aqui

          include_once("conecta.php");

          $idPrest = $_POST['id'];
          $razaoSoc = $_POST['razao_social'];
          $NomeFanta = $_POST['nome_fantasia'];
          $NumCnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
          $Tip = ['tipo'];

          $sql = "INSERT INTO cadastroprestador(ID_PREST,Razão_Social,Nome_Fantasia,CNPJ) VALUES ('$idPrest', '$razaoSoc', '$NomeFanta', '$NumCnpj')";
          mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die ("erro ao tentar cadastrar");

          echo "Cadastrado Com sucesso";
          mysqli_close($strcon);

   }
  ```

> **Porque validação do lado cliente (Front-end) e lado servidor (Back-end)?**

Validar dados sendo enviados pelo usuário só no javascript não é o suficiente por causa de:

- se o usuário desativar o javascript, você pode acabar com dados inválidos no servidor
- Porque o front-end fica acessível no navegador. E todo o código que lá está, pode acabar sendo alterado por alguém que tenha um conhecimento avançado e más intenções. O código JavaScript pode perfeitamente ser alterado e assim a validação pode ser burlada.
- validações no servidor fazem um site menos suscetível a robôs maliciosos

Em resumo... vale a pena precaver contra todos esses agentes desconhecidos, fazendo a validação no servidor (que é o agente mais confiável) como sendo a principal... e no javascript, como sendo um agilizador de validação, por não necessitar de ir no servidor.

Comment: leo, tentei colocar seu codigo tanto na começo quanto no fim, esta dando erro ainda

<?php

if (isset($_POST['enviar']){
    include_once("conecta.php");
    echo "Cadastrado Com sucesso";
}



$idPrest = $_POST['id'];
$razaoSoc = $_POST['razao_social'];
$NomeFanta = $_POST['nome_fantasia'];
$NumCnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
$Tip = ['tipo'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO cadastroprestador(ID_PREST,Razão_Social,Nome_Fantasia,CNPJ) VALUES ('$idPrest', '$razaoSoc', '$NomeFanta', '$NumCnpj')";
mysqli_query($sql) or die ("erro ao tentar cadastrar");
mysql_close($strcon);


?>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\estudo\cadastroPrestador.php on line 3

Comment: @MAGUIM faltou um parentesis de fechamento `if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){`

Comment: @MAGUIM do jeito q vc fez no comentário tá errado

Comment: tentei por mesmo assim esta dando erro, Notice: Undefined variable: strcon in C:\xampp2\htdocs\estudo\cadastroPrestador.php on line 14

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\estudo\cadastroPrestador.php on line 14
erro ao tentar cadastrar

Comment: @MAGUIM, `strcon` é a string da sua conexão. Não tinha percebido, o correto é `mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die ("erro ao tentar cadastrar");`

Comment: opa, mas agr parece esse erro aqui

 mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in line 14

Comment: obg pelo exemplo porem tive que fazer algumas mudanças, eu estava usando o xampp desatualizado e tava usando variaveis que ele nao reconhecia, entao atualizei o xampp e reestruturei o o codigo obg pela for e desculpa a minha ignorancia.

Answer (score 0):

Bom galera vou deixar com resolvido!

Tive que fazer algumas alterações do banco, Estava usando um Xampp desatualizado que não reconhecia as variáveis.

Outro ponto foi o modo de estruturar o código, Tive que fazer um codigo de iniciante para melhor entendimento do back-end.

Este erro que esta dando era porque estava esquecendo de usar a variável de conexão no query de inserção: ($strcon)

```
mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in line
```

e ficou assim:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($strcon, "INSERT INTO cadastroprestador(ID_PREST,Razao_Social,Nome_Fantasia,CNPJ) 
VALUES ('$idPrest', '$razaoSoc', '$NomeFanta', '$NumCnpj')");
```

segue como ficou estruturado o codigo:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Cadastro...</title>
</head>
<?php
$servidor='localhost';
$usuario='root';
$senha='';
$bancodedados='cis';
$strcon = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha,$bancodedados) or die ("não conectado com banco")
?>

<?php
$idPrest = $_POST['id'];
$razaoSoc = $_POST['razao_social'];
$NomeFanta = $_POST['nome_fantasia'];
$NumCnpj = $_POST['CNPJ'];
$Tip = $_POST['tipo'];
$sql = mysqli_query($strcon, "INSERT INTO cadastroprestador(ID_PREST,Razao_Social,Nome_Fantasia,CNPJ) 
VALUES ('$idPrest', '$razaoSoc', '$NomeFanta', '$NumCnpj')");

echo "Cadastro com Sucesso"


?>

</html>
```

Queria agradecer a paciência de todos obg

Abraços