# Formularios em PHP

Tags: php, html

tenho uma duvida e creio que seja muito simples de se resolver ,como faço para que não carregue o erro "Notice: Undefined index: cot " ,segue a baixo o código , sei que deve ser pq não existe nenhum valor,mas enfim.

teste

```
<body>
    <form mehthod="POST" action="">
        <input type="double" name="cot"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="ENVIAR">
        <hr>
        <?php
        $cot=$_GET["cot"];
        echo $cot;
        ?>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Joga um @ antes da variável $cot.

Comment: você pode utilizar também um `if`, exemplo:
`if(isset($_GET["cot"]){
  $cot = $_GET["cot"];
}`

Comment: Muitoo obrigado ,vou buscar mais a teoria ,vlww

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como resolver um Notice: Undefined index?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21714/como-resolver-um-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente verificar se a variável está "setada" antes. Segue código abaixo:

```
<?php
$cot = "";
if (isset($_GET["cot"])) {
    $cot = $_GET["cot"];
}
echo $cot;
?>
```

Também é possível fazer de forma mais 'elegante' utilizando If Ternário, mas do modo como fiz já resolve o seu problema.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: A partir do PHP 7 há o operador de coalescência nula: `$cot = $_GET['cot'] ?? ''`

Comment: Legal @AndersonCarlosWoss. Eu não conhecia. vou dar uma lida sobre o assunto. Obrigado por comentar.