# Variável de sessão fica vazia ao carregar página definida em <form action=""

Tags: php, session

Sou iniciante em php, estou fazendo um questionário como trabalho para faculdade...

Ao clicar em enviar, utilizando um `echo` na variável `$_SESSION['id']`, apresenta normalmente o conteúdo (recebe o último id inserido no banco de dados). Porém ao colocar no `<form action="resultado.php" method="post">` e carregar a página é retornado.

> Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\inteligencias\resultado.php on line 21

Preciso recuperar esse id em outra página para realizar consulta sql com o resultado.

### questoes.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Questionário</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("conecta.php");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (dt_resp) VALUES (NOW())");
    $st->execute();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $db->lastInsertId();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 28; ++$i) {
        $chave = 'P'.$i;
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO respostas (RESPOSTA, IDPERGUNTA, IDUSUARIO) VALUES (:resp, :perg, :id)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":resp", $_POST[$chave]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":perg", $i);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $ident);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

}
?>
<form action="resultado.php" method="post">    <!-- resultado.php -->
    <legend id="titulo">Inteligências Múltiplas</legend>
    <?php
    try {
        foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM perguntas") as $perguntas) {
            echo "<h4> $perguntas[ID]. $perguntas[ENUNCIADO] </h4>";
            echo "<input type ='radio'  id='concordo' name='P$perguntas[ID]' value = 'C' >Concordo<br>";
            echo "<input type ='radio'  id='discordo' name='P$perguntas[ID]' value = 'D' checked=checked >Discordo <br>";
        }
        $db = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro!: ".$e->getMessage()."</br>";
    }
    ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="acao" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### resultado.php:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Resultado</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
include("conecta.php");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você já fez este teste: <?php session_start(); ?>?

Comment: Coloque o atributo `name` dos radio buttons como `name='id'`.

Comment: @TaffarelXavier sim

Comment: @AugustoVasques  preciso capturar o id da pergunta que vem do banco de dados para inserir a resposta, por isso teoricamente não posso alterar. O $_SESSION['id'] é referente ao último id inserido na tabela de usuários.

Comment: Mas a questão levantada na pergunta é o fato de você não tem o parâmetro 'id' quando envia a requisição para *resultado.php* por isso que dá o erro ` Undefined index`. No `<form>` adicione um campo hidden cujo o `name='id'` e `value=$_SESSION['id']`

Answer (score 2):

**Para recuperar o `id`, que no caso, é uma chave na sessão, e não nas matrizes GET ou POST, você deve salvá-lo na `sessão`, e você não está fazendo isso, por isso o erro.**

---

Na verdade, seu erro é mais fácil do que poderíamos imaginar, aí, tem erro de lógica de programação. Como você editou seus códigos, ficou mais fácil percebê-lo.

Em primeiro lugar, você não está salvando um valor com a chave `id` na sessão infelizmente.

> Lembremos, acerca do php, que o erro `Notice: Undefined index:` não ocorre somente com as varíaveis $_GET e $_POST ou, indiretamente, em formulários, mas, na verdade, ocorre, no momento em que tentamos buscar um valor em um array pelo seu índice, mas que o mesmo não existe.
>
> Sinceramente, é incrível o desconhecimento de muitos acerca do que dizem:
>   
> [Como resolver um Notice: Undefined index?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21714/como-resolver-um-notice-undefined-index)
>   https://www.homehost.com.br/blog/tutoriais/php/notice-undefined-index-php/

**MASSA:** Esta questão, em inglês, responde como eu penso:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731693/undefined-index-with-php-sessions

### *"A razão para esses erros é que você está tentando ler uma chave de matriz que não existe."* No caso, na matriz $_SESSION. Pronto! É exatamente isso.

***Agora, vamos aos seus códigos:***

Veja bem: no arquivo `questoes.php`, você está fazendo o seguinte:  `$_SESSION['id'] = $db->lastInsertId();`, mas como isso vai ser salvo na matriz `$_SESSION`, sendo que está dentro de uma condição, na qual, seja necessário uma requisição POST?

A não ser que outro arquivo faça uma requisição para o arquivo `questões.php`, é impossível ter uma chave na sua sessão com este nome: **id**, impossibilitando, dessa forma, sua recuperação posteriormente, como você está tentando fazer no arquivo `resultado.php`.

Veja um exemplo usando seus mesmo arquivos, claro, tirei algumas coisas, que não tenho como adicioná-las, por exemplo, seus arquivos de configurações.

### Questoes.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Questionário</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//include("conecta.php");
//Veja que adiciono um valor com a chave id, somente para demonstração.
//Você já pode clicar em enviar para ir ao arquivo resultado.php, verás que aparecerá um valor aleatório.
$_SESSION['id'] = rand();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $st = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (dt_resp) VALUES (NOW())");
    $st->execute();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $db->lastInsertId();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 28; ++$i) {
        $chave = 'P'.$i;
        $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO respostas (RESPOSTA, IDPERGUNTA, IDUSUARIO) VALUES (:resp, :perg, :id)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":resp", $_POST[$chave]);
        $stmt->bindParam(":perg", $i);
        $stmt->bindParam(":id", $ident);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

}
?>
<form action="resultado.php" method="post">    <!-- resultado.php -->
    <legend id="titulo">Inteligências Múltiplas</legend>
    <?php
   /* try {
        foreach ($db->query("SELECT * FROM perguntas") as $perguntas) {
            echo "<h4> $perguntas[ID]. $perguntas[ENUNCIADO] </h4>";
            echo "<input type ='radio'  id='concordo' name='P$perguntas[ID]' value = 'C' >Concordo<br>";
            echo "<input type ='radio'  id='discordo' name='P$perguntas[ID]' value = 'D' checked=checked >Discordo <br>";
        }
        $db = null;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Erro!: ".$e->getMessage()."</br>";
    }*/
    ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="acao" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Resultado.php

```php
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Resultado</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
<button>Enviar</button>
</form>
<?php
//include("conecta.php");

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
//Por que não aparece o erro?
//Simples: você salvou na sessão um valor com a chave `id`, lá, quando iniciou o arquivo questoes.php
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

### Conclusão

Infelizmente, para resolver seu problema, eu precisaria entender suas regras de negócio, suas regras de sua aplicação. Você precisa salvar o id na sessão de outra forma, talvez, usando ajax ou usando o método $_GET, ali, no arquivo, questoes.php. Entretanto, uma coisa é muito certa: há erro de lógica de programação (php) na sua lógica.